# Visitor Pattern with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visitor-pattern

Let's say I have a visitor interface like this:

```
''' <remarks>Visitor Pattern</remarks>
Public Interface IVisitor
    Sub Visit(value As Type1)
    Sub Visit(value As Type2)
    Sub Visit(value As Type3)
    Sub Visit(value As Type4)
    Sub Visit(value As ...)
    ...
End Interface
```

Is there a way for my concrete visitors to avoid implementing Visit functions they don't need? I'd like to avoid doing stuff like this in my concrete visitors:

```
#Region "Methods not implemented (not needed)"

    Public Sub Visit(value As Type4) Implements IVisitor.Visit

    End Sub

    ...
```

I know that I can't use the `Overridable` keyword in `Interface`. So maybe I should just drop `Interface` for `Overridable Sub` in my base class?

Comment: Have you thought of using generics so that you only need to use one Visit method. e.g. Sub Visit<T>(value as T). Sorry if the syntax isn't 100% as I usually use C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a base class (may be marked by MustInherit, but not a must) which define a default implementation for all the methods. Every concrete Visitor will inherit the base class and override only the methods it needs to.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by "drop Interface". I think this is actually my only option. Thanks!